# ASP.NET how to use Sessions, when and where to declare it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve some data from db and store it some Session variable in order to have it in _Layout.cshtml on all pages, no matter what page the user will access from the start.
Global.asax:

`protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ...
            Manager mng = new Manager();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["company-cellphone"] = mng.GetContacts().CompanyCellphone;
        }`

Error: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which element is null in this code?

Comment: What does your method `GetContacts()` return; it looks like it is returning an uninitialised object. You need to check the return value and set if to a default value it is a null return

Comment: GetContacts() is returning a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to access the session from Application_Start but there is no live Session yet.

session is not available in all events of global.asax

**as a workaround try this:**

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)
     {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            ...
            Manager mng = new Manager();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["company-cellphone"] = mng.GetContacts().CompanyCellphone;
     }
 }
```

I'm not sure about your requirement but I would recommend to access the session in controller.initialize method

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
   base.Initialize(requestContext);
   //// access session here
   requestContext.HttpContext.Session["company-cellphone"]=mng.GetContacts().CompanyCellphone;
}
```

Comment: it worked in both places , thanks, but could you please explain why in the controller is better and do I need to make any checking before accessing session in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Application_Start runs before any sessions can be created.  And a session is specific to a single client connecting to your application.

You can create a static class and store the company-cellphone value in it.

In your Models folder create a new class file named Global.cs in that file create a static class with properties that will hold your application level information.

```
public static class Global
{
    static string companyCellPhone;

    public static string companyCellPhone
    {
    get
    {
        return this.companyCellPhone;
    }
    set
    {
        this.companyCellPhone= value;
    }
}
```

Then your Application_Start method would look something like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    Manager mng = new Manager();
    Global.companyCellPhone = mng.GetContacts().CompanyCellphone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that this is a single global value to be viewed by all users. In that case you could store the value in `HttpApplicationState` rather than `HttpSessionState:`

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application["YourValue"] = "SomeValue";
    }
}
```

I'm not necessarily advocating its use. But just as `Session` can store user-specific values, `Application` stores values that are global to the application.